# .net dbnull.value sqlparameter where

Tags: .net, dbnull, sqlparameter

I have a probleme with a sql query :

I would like do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [myBoolField] IS NULL
```

if i run this query, i have my results,

but i would like use parameters, so i add :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [myBitField] IS @myBitField
```

with

```
New SqlParameter("@myBitField", dbnull.value)
```

i have an error at the @myBoolField

if i pass a value like true or false, that's work ( with " = @myBitField")

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only test for NULL using `IS NULL`. You cannot use parameters and there wouldn't really be any point.

`DBNull.Value` can be used when inserting or comparing values in code, but not on `WHERE` conditions since NULL is not equal to even another NULL.

Comment: oh... okay, but dbnull.value is NULL, so it's strange, no ? And as you said you can use it for insert for example

Comment: @Testman when using parameters the query is usually parsed beforehand and the parameters are not just substituted into the string. The parser will see `IS @parameter` and say "nope, that's not acceptable" and that's it.